# Error when Calling a Java Method

Tags: java, methods

I am new to Java and am having an issue calling a method. I was hoping someone might be able to help me figure out what is going on.

The code I have is as follows:

```
public class QuickFindUF
{
    private int[] id;
    public QuickFindUF(int N)
    {
        id = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            id[i] = i;
    }

    public boolean connected(int p, int q)
    { return id[p] == id[q]; }

    public void union(int p, int q)
    {
        int pid = id[p];
        int qid = id[q];
        for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
            if (id[i] == pid) id[i] = qid;
    }
}
```

I took a look on Stack and figured the [way to call my method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285657/calling-a-method-in-java) would be using the following code: `QuickFindUF x = new QuickFindUF(10);`

When I run this I get an error that says

```
QuickFindUF.java:27: error: class, interface, or enum expected
QuickFindUF x = new QuickFindUF(10);
^
1 error
```

If someone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: The 27 is the line number that's causing the problem. It looks like the problem is in code you haven't shown us. (The line calling `new QuickFindUF` isn't part of the file you've shown so far.)

Comment: I suspect you're not calling your constructor from within a main() method (or similar)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the code you posted is your complete code, it appears you need a main method.

```
public class QuickFindUF
{
    //
    // add this so you can run code when your program executes
    //
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        QuickFindUF x = new QuickFindUF(10);
        //
        // call your methods on x here
        // e.g.
        // boolean connected = x.connected(2, 3);
        //
    }

    private int[] id;
    public QuickFindUF(int N)
    {
        id = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            id[i] = i;
    }

    public boolean connected(int p, int q)
    { return id[p] == id[q]; }

    public void union(int p, int q)
    {
        int pid = id[p];
        int qid = id[q];
        for (int i = 0; i < id.length; i++)
            if (id[i] == pid) id[i] = qid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got one more quick question: when I run `x.union(0,1);`, outside the code block, I don't get an error. But when I try to run `x.show();` to see the output, I get an error. Any clue why that would happen?

Comment: What does your `show()` method do? What is the error you're getting? And what do you mean by outside of the code block?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear and for the blatant typo (should say "inside the code block"). I thought `.show()` allowed me to see the output.  When I ran `x.union(0,1)` and `x.show` where you said to call the methods on `x` I get an error that says: `error: cannot find symbol
  x.show();
   ^
  symbol:   method show()
  location: variable x of type QuickFindUF
1 error`

Comment: That error means that you do not have a method named `show` defined on the class.  Based on the posted code, you only have `union` and `connected` as available methods.
You probably want to use `x.toString()`.  It is built in, however, to make it useful you should define your own `public string toString() { return "foo"; }`  Just replace `"foo"` with actual code that displays your object.

Answer (score 1):

Your main method  might be  outside the class , You need to declare main method inside the class like this way :

```
public static void main(String []args){

QuickFindUF x = new QuickFindUF(10);

}
```